# Running multiple R scripts sequentially from shell in the same R session

Tags: r, bash, shell, rscript

Is it possible to run multiple .R files from the shell or a bash script, in sequence, in the same R session (so without having to write intermediate results to disk)?

E.g. if file1.R contains `a=1` and file2.R `print(a+1)`

then do something like

```
$ Rscript file1.R file2.R
[1] 2
```

(of course a workaround would be to stitch the scripts together or have a master script sourcing 1 and 2)

Comment: you have the bash as a tag, why don't you make a multine bash code then ?

Comment: a bash script calling Rscript twice will also instantiate two R sessions, and return " 'a' not found" in the second one.

Comment: oh - then you need to make a wrapper with 'source' command - sb made an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a wrapper script that calls each script in turn:

```r
source("file1.R")
source("file2.R")
```

Call this `source_files.R` and then run `Rscript source_files.R`. Of course, with something this simple you can also just pass the statements on the command line:

```sh
Rscript -e 'source("file1.R"); source("file2.R")'
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this was my 'master script' workaround. Was wondering if there was a way of avoiding it, but it's definitely a way.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer really helped me, thank you!

In poking around the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/Rscript), I also discovered that Rscript also takes multiple expressions, provided each expression is preceded by the "-e" flag.

So, this would also work:

```
Rscript -e "source('file1.R')" -e "source('file2.R')" [args]
```